# how to assign PHP script to a variable in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to write php script in a file.It was sure to get Parsing error on that.Help me assign php code to a php variable so i can write it on code.

```
<?php

$myFile = "testFile1.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "<?php some php code with functions ?>";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

Comment: Can't understand your question/problem.

Comment: writing php in to a file with php is usually a bad idea

Comment: @Dagon not always. For example, creating a configuration file.

Comment: @Hast but having your browser editable config file be code is not a good idea. Use XML or INI, never PHP.

Comment: @Dagon and how about framework or CMS web installers?

Comment: @Hast Those are bad ideas too. They are great for letting novice users install complex software they don't understand that opens them up to total pwnage.

Comment: BTW, its a good idea to start getting used to double quoted strings. More of a hassle, but they're more functional and it's good practice consideration most other languages use double quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
    <?php

    $myFile = "testFile1.php";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $var1 = 'value1';
    $var2 = 'value2';

    $stringData =
        '<?php $var1 = ' . $var1 . ';
        $var2 = ' . $var2 . ';
        do_something($var1); ?>';

    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

    fclose($fh);

?>
```

So just use single quotes to make sure php won't parse vars as php vars themselves, and use concatenation to put var value in the file. You also probably may use [var_export($var, true)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) function in some cases.

Comment: Don't use a preassigned file name. If another process attempts to write to that one as the other one is reading, _ **all hell will break loose!** _

Answer (score 3):

Put the string in single quotes, that you want to write to the file, otherwise it's interpreted.

```
$stringData = '<?php some php code ?>';
```

Alternatively, you could escape the code, see the chapter "Strings" in the php manual for more details: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes:

```
<?php

$myFile = "testFile1.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = '<?php some php code ?>';
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

fclose($fh);

?>
```

Comment: What if the 'some php code' contains a `'` in it?  Heredoc might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? Anyways, you can't. But you can ask PHP for a ransoms temp file name, create that file, write the code there, then `include` the file.

Also, you need to use single quotes otherwise PHP will attempt to interpret it.

```
$phpCrapThatWillMakeSiteVulnerableToHacking = '<?php echo "Welcome to my easially hackable website. Now I will execute $_POST["code"]!"; ' . $_POST["code"] . ' ?>';
$fileName = tempnam("/tmp", "derp");
$handle = fopen($fileName, "w");
if ($handle === FALSE)
{
    die("I derped");
}
fwrite($handle, $phpCrapThatWillMakeSiteVulnerableToHacking);
fclose($handle);
include($fileName);
```

Comment: I have SQLIED a website that  ranking under 3000.I have access to /proc of that so I can get or put data/file on directory that is writable.I was facing the problem while writing a php file on the server.I Know  very well that it will make the webi vulnerable .LOL :P @ColeJohnson

Comment: @Injector I just died when I saw your name!

Comment: @ColeJohnson I vomited on your body the S hole.

Answer (score 0):

Split the problem. Just like in JavaScript you use `<\/script>` or `"<"+"/script"`, in PHP you can write `"?".">"`.

This prevents the `?>` token from being recognised.

Additionally, NOWDOC is intended for putting PHP code in a string:

```
$phpcode = <<<'END'
Blah blah blah
This is code with $variables, functions() and {$complex['syntax']}
END;
```

Comment: That token within a string wouldn't really matter.

Comment: Was known to me about JS parsing. but thanks to you i got to know about PHP.Now I will  try splitting into smaller variables and then i will append all the variables in a single one to write.